# PySpark: Convert Map Column Keys Using Dictionary

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a map column as below:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- map_col: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = true)
```

The `map_col` has keys which need to be converted based on a dictionary. For example, the dictionary might be:

```
mapping = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '5', 'd': '8' }
```

So, the `DataFrame` needs to change from:

```
[Row(id=123, map_col={'a': 0.0, 'b': -42.19}),
  Row(id=456, map_col={'a': 13.25, 'c': -19.6, 'd': 15.6})]
```

to the following:

```
[Row(id=123, map_col={'1': 0.0, '2': -42.19}),
  Row(id=456, map_col={'1': 13.25, '5': -19.6, '8': 15.6})]
```

I see that `transform_keys` is an option if I could write-out the dictionary, but it's too large and dynamically-generated earlier in the workflow. I think an `explode`/`pivot` could also work, but seems non-performant?

Any ideas?

**Edit**: Added a bit to show that size of `map` in `map_col` is not uniform.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting `0.0`, `-42.19`, etc? What happens when the "mapping" has duplicate keys? Or you rename `a` to `b`, and `b` already exists in `map_col`?

Comment: _it's too large and dynamically-generated earlier in the workflow_ - Why do these matter? You could broadcast the dict to make it accessible across executors

Comment: Does your map column always contain the same number of keys? Or is it at least limited by a known number?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm catching this whole DataFrame from an earlier process/job. The mapping will not have duplicate keys (in either `map_col` or the `mapping` dictionary. The renamed values are guaranteed to not overlap, either.

About the too large, I meant hat my understanding of `transform_key` is that it must be written-out as part of an `expr`. I certainly can broadcast the dictionary, however.

Comment: @Arseny No - the keys are some subset - not necessarily same length - of a larger set of unique possibilities. They are limited by a known number - could be up to about 400 or so unique keys.

Comment: `transform_keys` can use a `lambda`, as shown in the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform_keys.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform-keys), it's not just limited to an `expr`. If the dictionary is available in your pipeline, you could refer to it in the `lambda` i.e; `df.select(transform_keys('map_col', lambda k, _: mapping[k]))`

Comment: @danielcahall Ah! Did not know that. May be a simple question, then. Let me try and get back.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it may just limited to functions provided by `pyspark.sql.functions`. Let me poke around and give a correct answer.

Comment: Yea - looks like that doesn't support Python-defined UDFs. Only functions in `pyspark.sql.functions`. That is almost exactly what I want, thoiugh

Comment: Though belated, see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform_keys` can use a `lambda`, as shown in the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform_keys.html#pyspark-sql-functions-transform-keys), it's not just limited to an `expr`. However, the `lambda` or Python callable will need to utilize a function either defined in `pyspark.sql.functions`, a `Column` method, or a Scala UDF, so using a Python UDF which refers to the `mapping` dictionary object isn't currently possible with this mechanism. However, we can make use of the [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) function to apply the mapping, by unrolling the key-value pairs in the `mapping` into chained `when` conditions. See the below example to illustrate the idea:

```py
from typing import Dict, Callable
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql.functions import Column, when, transform_keys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def apply_mapping(mapping: Dict[str, str]) -> Callable[[Column, Column], Column]:

    def convert_mapping_into_when_conditions(key: Column, _: Column) -> Column:
        initial_key, initial_value = mapping.popitem()
        initial_condition = when(key == initial_key, initial_value)
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x.when(key == y[0], y[1]), mapping.items(), initial_condition)

    return convert_mapping_into_when_conditions


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("Temp")\
        .getOrCreate()
    df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, {"foo": -2.0, "bar": 2.0})], ("id", "data"))
    mapping = {'foo': 'a', 'bar': 'b'}
    df.select(transform_keys(
        "data", apply_mapping(mapping)).alias("data_transformed")
              ).show(truncate=False)
```

The output of the above is:

```
+---------------------+
|data_transformed     |
+---------------------+
|{b -> 2.0, a -> -2.0}|
+---------------------+
```

which demonstrates the defined mapping (`foo -> a, bar -> b`) was successfully applied to the column. The `apply_mapping` function should be generic enough to copy and utilize in your own pipeline.

Comment: This is clever. Very nice - and thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing! This was a fun one to figure out actually. :)

Comment: You dont need a udf. udfs are expensive. transform keys should be a one liner to bring this down

Comment: Agreed, but this is not a UDF. ‘transform_keys’ does not support Python UDFs. This is a function being supplied which utilizes the built in pyspark function ‘when’.

Answer (score 2):

an approach using RDD transformation.

```py
def updateKey(theDict, mapDict):
    """
    update theDict's key using mapDict
    """

    updDict = []
    for item in theDict.items():
        updDict.append((mapDict[item[0]] if item[0] in mapDict.keys() else item[0], item[1]))
    
    return dict(updDict)

data_sdf.rdd. \
    map(lambda r: (r[0], r[1], updateKey(r[1], mapping))). \
    toDF(['id', 'map_col', 'new_map_col']). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
# |id |map_col                            |new_map_col                        |
# +---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
# |123|{a -> 0.0, b -> -42.19, e -> 12.12}|{1 -> 0.0, 2 -> -42.19, e -> 12.12}|
# |456|{a -> 13.25, c -> -19.6, d -> 15.6}|{8 -> 15.6, 1 -> 13.25, 5 -> -19.6}|
# +---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

*P.S., I added a new key within the map_col's first row to show what happens if no mapping is available*

Comment: This worked great, and I want to comment and point-out that `transform_keys` is only available in Spark >3.1. The above works for older versions - in case someone reading has an older codebase.

Comment: @wwnde this is an RDD transformation that uses a python function within map. is this still considered expensive? I thought spark will broadcast the function to executors.

Comment: This solution is good, and does not utilize a UDF. I don’t believe UDFs are actually supported in the RDD API.

Comment: @samkart, you are right. So the def and assumed it was registered as a udf. me bad

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Use itertools to create an expression to inject into pysparks transform_keys function. Used upper just in case. Code below

```
   from itertools import chain

m_expr1 = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*mapping.items())])


new =df.withColumn('new_map_col',transform_keys("map_col", lambda k, _: upper(m_expr1[k])))

new.show(truncate=False)

+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|id |map_col                            |new_map_col                        |
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|123|{a -> 0.0, b -> -42.19}            |{1 -> 0.0, 2 -> -42.19}            |
|456|{a -> 13.25, c -> -19.6, d -> 15.6}|{1 -> 13.25, 5 -> -19.6, 8 -> 15.6}|
+---+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```